# Why is this comma mapping not working for me in GVim?

Tags: vim

I want to use the comma key as a leader for shortcuts, so I tried to map the original `,` functionality to `,,` with this line:

`noremap ,, ,`

It worked fine in terminal, but in GVim it just gives off a warning sound and nothing happens. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I also tried mapping other keys to `,` but they didn't work either (same outcome, giving off an alert sound). The only way I can get the `,` function to work now is to press `,` once and then wait. Does anybody have some idea what could possibly be the reason it is not working for me?

Comment: Guess you are talking about normal mode. The `,` means "Repeat latest f, t, F or T in opposite direction". If there is no character to jump to, it will beep. I use the comma  for some of my mappings. If I want the "Repeat latest..." I just hit the comma and wait a moment. Vim realizes that no key is following and does the default comma-action. I also tested `noremap ,, ,` in terminal and gui. It works.

Comment: @user7369280 I understand the mapping should work, but it is just not working for me. Strange. (Also I'm sure there are characters to jump back to.)

Answer (score 0):

So I found out why it is not working and I'll post it as an answer here. Basically, it was because I had the plugin fanfingtastic which replaced the original comma to an enhanced one, so the correct mapping for me should be:

`map ,, <Plug>fanfingtastic_,`